# Proof for functions of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning

Let $A \in \text{Mat} (n,n,\mathbb{C})$. Let $I$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Further, let $f:I\to\mathbb{C}$ and $g:I\to\mathbb{C}$ be two functions for which $f(A)$ and $g(A)$ are defined. 
How to prove the following two statements for the two functions $(f+g)(A): I\to \mathbb{C}$ and $(f\cdot g)(A): I\to \mathbb{C}$:

i) The matrix $(f+g)(A)$ is defined and it holds that $(f+g)(A) = f(A) + g(A)$.

ii) The matrix $(f\cdot g)(A)$ is defined and it holds that $(f\cdot g)(A) = f(A) \cdot g(A)$.

Edit: At the downvoters of this question: If I could understand what to do here, I would solve it myself. It's actually because I first thought I missed important information that I posted it here. It's the *actual* exercise, please bear that in mind.

Comment: Why are $f(A)$ or $g(A)$ defined for matrices if $f,g:I\to\Bbb C$?

Comment: There are various ways to define a function of a square matrix: the general term is [functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus).  Your two statements are among the properties any functional calculus is designed to have.  Which functional calculus are you asking about?

Comment: Oh sorry, the latter two properties refer to the two functions $(f+g)(A): I \to \mathbb{C}$ and $(f\cdot g):I\to \mathbb{C}$. I will edit the OP.

Comment: In order to prove these things, you need a definition of what $f(A)$ *means* for $f:I \to \Bbb C$.  That is, you need a "functional calculus".  *Which specific definition of $f(A)$ do you want to work with?*

Comment: I found this exercise without any further comment on the definition of f(A). Actually, this is the precise reason I asked it here on math.stackexchange.

Comment: @Taufi it might help to reference where the question came from in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple first and define $f(A)$ for matrices $A$ which are diagonalizable. If $A = VDV^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal, define $f(A) = Vf(D)V^{-1}$, where
$$ f(D) = \text{diag}(f(d_1), f(d_2), \dotsc, f(d_n))$$
is the diagonal matrix obtained by applying $f$ to the individual entries of $D$. Here it is straight forward to verify parts 1 and 2.

Push to general matrices and smooth functions via the Jordan decomposition, see the Wikipedia definition for appropriate way of doing this,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function

You will need Leibniz's rule for differentiating a product.

At some point you might want to have a look at Higham's book on matrix functions, see

http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/fm/

It is about as good as they come.

Comment: @Taufi: You are very welcome. Kind regards